# How can I map pixel position i,j to a color?

Tags: java, swing, colors, graphics2d

I am trying to make it so that the position of a pixel in an image (int i, int j) determines the color of that pixel. This is for an explosion effect in a java2d game I want to be extra cool by making the colors of the explosion depend on the position of the explosion. What I am doing currently is creating an `ArrayList` of colors then using `i*j` as index, testing this out on a 1000x1000 image shows a mirroring along the diagonal, naturally because `i*j = j*i` around the diagonal as show below.

Knowing that `i=0, j=999` is the 1000th pixel while `i=999, j=0` is the 999001th pixel how would you get a mapping `f(i,j) != f(j,i)` of pixels to colors without first storing the colors in a list? The color ordering is very important, that is to say colors are constructed using `R,0,0` then `0,G,0` then `0,0,B`

Question wasn't clear apparently.
Notice `getAllColors`, it creates the colors in order and adds them to the list, notice `g2d.setColor(i*j)`, it sets the color in order except it mirrors along the diagonal. I want to know if I can map the colors to an index(in order) without storing it in a list while avoiding mirroring along the diagonal.

Full MCVE

```
public class AllColors extends JPanel {

private int width, height;
private double colorIncrement;
private List<Color> colors;

public AllColors(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.colorIncrement = 1.0 / Math.pow(1.0 * width * height, 1.0 / 3);
    this.colors = new ArrayList<>(width * height);
    getAllColors();
}

@Override
@Transient
public Color getBackground() {
    return Color.black;
}

@Override
@Transient
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            // Notice i*j= j*i around diagonal, the problem
            g2d.setColor(colors.get(i * j));
            g2d.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}

private void getAllColors() {
    for (float R = 0; R < 1.0; R += colorIncrement)
        for (float G = 0; G < 1.0; G += colorIncrement)
            for (float B = 0; B < 1.0; B += colorIncrement)
                colors.add(new Color(R, G, B));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    AllColors allColors = new AllColors(800, 800);

    frame.getContentPane().add(allColors);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Um ... what's the question

Comment: i * j is commutative so you need something like i * constant + j

Answer (score 0):

In the double loop check when i=j then skip the payload.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing that `i=0, j=999` is the 1000th pixel while `i=999, j=0` is the 999001th pixel how would you get a mapping `f(i,j) != f(j,i)` of pixels to colors without first storing the colors in a list?

```
pixel = i * 1000 + j + 1;
```

As far as storing them in a list is concerned, that may be your best approach, since precalculation can often make things faster. Though I would probably do a two dimensional array. Like:

```
private void getAllColors() {
    colors = new Color[1000][1000];
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    loop:
    for (float R = 0; R < 1.0; R += colorIncrement) {
        for (float G = 0; G < 1.0; G += colorIncrement) {
            for (float B = 0; B < 1.0; B += colorIncrement) {
                colors[i++][j] = new Color(R, G, B));
                if (i == 1000) {
                    j++;
                    i = 0;
                    if (j == 1000) break loop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```